# Need suggestions for avoiding duplicate code in selenium webdriver @Test method

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, repeat

I need to validate the complete flow of a form.
**On screen1:**
-Take input on different fields from user
-Click on Submit button
**On Screen 2:**
Click on Confirmation button
**On Screen3:**
Click on Finalize button to complete the entire flow.

TestNG :
I have written separate test classes. Each test class has a single @Test method.

```
Class1
{
@Test
public static void verifyScreen1SubmitButton()
{
selenium code1 to input values
Click on Submit button
Assert statement
}
}

Class2
{
@Test
public static void verifyScreen2ConfirmationButton()
{
**selenium code1 to input values
Click on Submit button**
Click on Confirmation button
Assert statement
}
}

Class3
{
@Test
public static void verifyScreen2FinalizeButton()
{
**selenium code1 to input values
Click on Submit button
Click on Confirmation button**
Click on Finalize button
Assert statement
}
}
```

Every next class is using the data input and code from previous class as it is the next page of the form. There is so much repetition of the code. Please suggest the best possible way in TestNG to minimize this code repetition.

Comment: Write a single class with 3 tests as different methods and avoid closing browser. So, ideally you will have to click only on Confirmation button and Finalize buttons in second and third test respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do following :

```
Class1
{

@Test
public static void method1()
{
     //Code to execute
}
@Test
public static void method2()
{
     //Code to execute
}
@Test
public static void method3()
{
    //Code to execute
}
```

So here you will need only one class instead of 3. Also you can set methods priority to run it. For ex : `priority=0,priority=1` so you can run methods in your favorite order to achieve actual flow.